# Markerwithlabel doesn't get created

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the following the api wrapper: https://github.com/jmelosegui/GooglemapMvc

It isn't possible with the api to create an marker with a label, so i am modifying the javascript myself.

This works fine (Creating a normal marker):

```
  var markerOptions = {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.Latitude, this.Longitude),
            map: this.EnableMarkersClustering ? null : this.Map,
            title: this.Title,
            clickable: this.Clickable,
            draggable: this.Draggable,
        };


        // create marker
        this.GMarker = new Marker(markerOptions);
```

This does not (Creating a marker with a label):

```
            // create marker
        this.GMarker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.Latitude, this.Longitude),
            map: this.EnableMarkersClustering ? null : this.Map,
            title: this.Title,
            clickable: this.Clickable,
            draggable: this.Draggable,
            // Self added
            raiseOnDrag: true,
            labelContent: "A",
            labelStyle: { opacity: 0.75 },
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
            labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
            labelInBackground: false,
            labelVisible: true,
            optimized: false,
            icon: {}
    });

        // Anything below here won't be reached!
        console.log("marker!");
```

Why doesn't it reach the console.log?

Comment: Cant see a markerWithLabel type in this api. Maybe you need the the markerwithlabel.js?

Comment: @StevenWeb I didn't know i had to include another script for markerwithlabel.. This solved my problem, thank you very much! If you create an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i think you are missing the `markerwithlabel.js` [LINK](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js?r=131)